# Getting video streaming data from a flash player to view it on Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, video-streaming, flash, windows-phone

Is it possible to investigate an html page that views a video streaming data using flash, and then use these data to view it on the phone?

for example [Al Jazeera website](http://www.aljazeera.com/watch_now/) has a streaming service. I've looked through the html page and other resources using chrome developers tools. I found a lot of data, but couldnt figure it out which data I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Flash uses a video format (codec) which isn't supported by Windows Phone.

If you want to be able to play such videos you'll need to get them in the appropriate format or transcode them yourself.

Comment: I see, thanks for answering. By the way, I love your blog, keep it up :)